# Google Sheets - Sort into a New Tab Based on 2 Columns

Tags: google-sheets

My department works off of a large Google Sheet fed by a form that clients fill out. They can select various things they want designed on that form. I then use a formula to sort that main sheet into tabs based on what they selected (i.e. - clients can select to have a postcard, billboard, newspaper ad, or eblast designed, and each of those filter into their own tabs).

I'm using the formula:

```
=query('Form Responses'!B1:AK,"Select * Where F = 'EBlast' ")
```

However we would like to offer the ability to add on an eblast to any order, at a lower charge - utilizing a yes/no question that would feed into a different column (column O).

So I need the formula above to essentially read as:
Select Where F = EBlast or O = Yes

I've tried various things, including:

```
=query('Form Responses'!B1:AK,"Select * Where F = 'EBlast' ", "Select * Where O = 'Yes' ")

=query('Form Responses'!B1:AK,"Select * Where F = 'EBlast' * O='Yes' ")

=query('Form Responses'!B1:AK,"Select * Where F = 'EBlast' * O='Yes' OR Where O = 'Yes'")
```

Any ideas?

I can share the sheet if necessary, but would prefer not to as it has client information in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AND like this:

```
=query('Form Responses'!B1:AK,"Select * Where F = 'EBlast' and O='Yes' ")
```